# Holoviews: How to plot DataFrame with time index

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, holoviews

I am trying to plot a Pandas DataFrame (more pecisely one column of it) with a timestamped index using Holoviews DFrame class and the corresponding `Curve` method. There are two problems:

1) I do not know how to access the index once the DataFrame is inside the DFrame.

2) I get a TypeError when including the index explicitly as a column and calling `Curve`.

See here for the full notebook
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/bjonen/492fea9559fd73edf579/raw/ac01b49edde36bf621d90cc390baa790621290bd/holoviews_plt_tseries.ipynb

The documentation has an example with Timestamps but in this example a `HoloMap` is generated and not a `Curve`.

After doing some more investigation, it seems that `Curve` expects some kind of numerical data as `kdim`. The `TypeError` occurs when internally np.vstack is called on numpy arrays of float and object type.

Any hints are well appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for HoloViews http://holoviews.org/Tutorials/Pandas_Conversion.html indicates that pandas indices are dropped when ingested into a HoloView Table.  The solution to your problem might be to simply call the method 'reset_index()' on your data frame prior to putting it in HoloViews.

Comment: Currently indices are ignored by HoloViews so using reset_index is the correct solution. In future we will extend the pandas interface to add support for indices.